# How i should set javascript global variable to get its value properly

Tags: html, autocomplete, ruby-on-rails-3.2, coffeescript

I have two html elements on my page. One is dropdown and other is text field(which is working as autocomplete).

```
     <select id="match_engine_brand" name="match_engine[brand]" class="hidden-field"><option value="">Select Brand</option><option value="3">addidas</option>
        <option value="5">cat</option>
        <option value="2">nike</option>
        <option value="4">panther</option>
        <option value="6">tower</option></select>
```

while text field is

```
     <input class="string required ui-autocomplete-input" id="match_engine_shoe_model" name="match_engine[shoe_model]" placeholder="select model of shoe using autocomplete" required="required" size="50" type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

My cofeescript code is below

```
     $(document).ready ->

       $("#match_engine_brand").change ->
           window.flag_value =  $(this).val()
           alert(window.flag_value) #value display in alert

       $('#match_engine_shoe_model').autocomplete
         source: "/user/match_shoes/shoes?id="+window.flag_value
         select: (event, ui) -> $("#match_engine_shoe_model").val(ui.item.id)
```

In autocomplete function

```
window.flag_value       #give me undefined value    
$('#match_engine_brand :selected').val()   #give me undefined value
```

How i can get dropdown value in autocomplete function.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

You need to have an initiated value of `window.flag_value`. Otherwise if you don't change `#match_engine_branch`, this var has no value. That's the reason of `undefined value`.

The way to solve it is to define this var before

```
$(document).ready ->
  window.flag_value = "something"
  ...
```

However I think it's unnecessary to use global var. Check it in function should work.

```
$('#match_engine_shoe_model').autocomplete ->
  dropdown_value = $("#match_engine_brand").val() ? "something"
```

Comment: dropdown_value = $("#match_engine_brand").val() || "something". This line in autocomplete give me syntax error. If i write this properly then my problem will be solved. please help

Comment: help me please i have describe my problem above

Comment: @Kashiftufail, I get used to Ruby's pipes equal and forget Coffee's special syntax :) Question mark is the right way to go. Sorry about that. Fixed.

Comment: `a = b || c` is [perfectly valid](http://coffeescript.org/#try:dropdown_value%20%3D%20%24(%22%23match_engine_brand%22).val()%20%7C%7C%20%22something%22) syntax...

Comment: @AlexWayne, thanks for mentioning that. I tried both of them in my console, `d = a || "something"` raised "Reference error: a is not defined", while `d = a ? "something"` actually returned "something". See http://coffeescript.org/#operators - The existential operators for details. I think `?` is more suitable for this case as `val()` could be either undefined or null.

Comment: give me null see ajax call        GET http://localhost:3000/user/match_shoes/shoes?id=null&&term=ad 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: in firefox console it give me value $("#match_engine_brand").val(). But in ajax call give null. why? don't know problem

Comment: @BillyChan `||` will, just like in js, return the second operand if the first is a falsy value, which includes `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: @Kashiftufail, I guess you forget to replace `window.flag_value` with `dropdown_value` in url construction. null id will certainly produce error.